# Cross Compiling with Cmake. What should I expect from cross compiling

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling

I also want the code I developed for Linux to work on Windows. I wrote simple Hello world code for this. I was able to create the .exe file with minGW using Cmake. When I run the .exe file directly on Windows, I got the error "libstdc++-6.dll not found" even though it exists on my computer. When I deleted the contents of the /build folder in Windows and built it with Cmake, the newly created .exe file worked. When I compile directly with minGW without using Cmake, the .exe worked without problems.
Is it a mistake to transfer the .exe file with its source codes to the Windows environment and expect it to work directly? I want to understand the logic of this concept properly.

Comment: ***Windows, I got the error "libstdc++-6.dll not found" even though it exists on my computer.*** You have to tell your OS where to look for the dlls if the dll is not in the same folder as your executable. You can add an entry to your PATH environment variable to the folder containing the dll or one of the other methods described in this Microsoft document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications

Comment: *"exists on my computer"* Because you copied it from the cross-compiler, or you had it from elsewhere? Mixing those dlls from different MinGW flavors is a bad idea, don't do that.

Comment: "What should I expect from cross compiling" - Pain, suffering, hard work, poor debug experience, occasional hard earned success.

Comment: Do you _really_ want to cross-compile, or do you want to build your code on Windows to run on Windows?  These are two different things.

Comment: This is not what's referred to as cross-compiling. Cross-compiling would be you compiling for arm on a x86 machine or for windows on a linux OS. If you're only trying to compile a hello world application, you imho just make your life harder by trying to use minGW. You can generate a CMake project for Visual Studio which has a much higher chance of running without the need to deploy additional binaries.

Answer (score 1):

If you use libraries that are not part of Windows itself, you will generally need to distribute the DLLs for those libraries in the same directory as the EXE in order for your EXE to work on another computer.

Alternatively, many cross-compilers support a `-static` argument that you can pass at link time in order to statically link these libraries into your executable.  I favor that approach, but the licensing requirements for it are stricter.

(Make sure you follow the license terms for any software you redistribute that isn't your own, open source or otherwise.)

Comment: And the required DLLs should be provided with the cross-compiler.